# How to make my phone vibrate when a text or an email is received when in vibrate mode?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sms, email, notifications, vibration

Currently, when I put my phone into vibrate mode, it only vibrates for calls. It does nothing for texts or emails, however, so I don't know when I've received one. Does anyone know a way to enable vibrating when a text or an email is received? My phone is an HTC Eris rooted with Cyanogen Mod if that helps.

Answer (score 8):

You can enable vibrate for SMS from `Messaging -> Menu key -> Settings -> Notification settings -> Vibrate`. Not sure about Email since I use K-9 (in case you use it too it's in the app, `Long-press the account -> Account settings -> Notifications -> Vibrate`).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this helps, but I have a Samsung Galaxy S2.

I use GO SMS Pro for texting, instead of the stock Messaging app.
The vibration settings can be configure through the app itself.
In the stock Messaging app, I could not find any option for vibration.

Answer (score 1):

If your phone is in Vibration mode then by default the phone vibrates for a small amount of time if you receive an SMS.

To customize it, I mean to increase the Vibration to a little longer period you have to install some applications from the Android Market.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Galaxy ii to vibrate when your receive a text:

1. Go to the "conversations" page in the Messaging application (stock). ie. where you can view a list of your conversations.
2. Hit the "Menu" button
3. Select "Setting" from the "Menu" list
4. Find "Notification settings" towards the bottom of the page.
5. Select "Vibrate" then, "Always"

Answer (score 0):

Look under vibration intensity/ notifications turn it up and it will work for messages